# Good way to do rsync relay for a chain of network hosts

Tags: rsync, synchronization

Below is the topology of network chain I have for a content syncing job:

```
  Host1       ->       Host2      ->     Host3
src-folder         dest-folder1        dest-folder2
```

I plan to use rsync as the underlying tool to do the sync since rsync is thoroughly tested and has really good performance and reputation in industry. However, from the rsync internals explained [here](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html), I think there is an issue if rsync jobs for `Host1` to `Host2` and `Host2` to `Host3` are executed in parallel, leading to `Host3` only gets partial/corrupted files from `Host2` in `dest-folder2`.

Please let me know if my concern is correct, and provide me a good way to resolve it if this is indeed an issue. Also for some reason, there is not a direct way to connect from `Host1` to `Host3` to sync the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your end goal? Syncing Host1 with Host3? What is the transport protocol you want to use? If you use SSH, it should be possible to use `Host2` only as an intermediary proxy without actually writing out any data there.

Comment: Hi Sven, I want to achieve the goal that the content from Host1 is synced to both Host2 and Host3 ultimately.